# Use process builder to initiate class?

Tags: java, class, process, processbuilder

I was wondering if it's possible in java to use a process builder to initiate an instance of a class..

Like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new OtherClass());
Process my_other_class = pb.start();
```

Or something like that.. Is this even possible..?

Comment: I know that this isn't even what process builders are for.. Idk what one would use though.. So, If i could get some help that'd be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Here - [java.lang.Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). I think you need to brush up with an introductory Java text as well.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, you should rephrase it.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish, and why do you *want* to use `ProcessBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` is for initiating another `Process` or in short, for launching a new copy of a program.

To run another `public static void main(String[] args)` method you will need to combine `ProcessBuilder` with the `java` command line argument and all of its parameters (class path, etc).  This will create a new instance of that class, **in another JVM**

To create another instance of a class in the same JVM, you simply need to call `new ClassName(parameters);`

If you want the new class to run *independent of the launching block of code*, then you will need to make sure the class `implements Runnable` or `extends Thread` and is launched appropriately; however, the *initialization* is still done in the constructor.

Since both instances are *initialized* by the code in their constructors, it is not clear *what kind* of initialization you are seeking.  All classes are intialized in their constructor(s), so adding `ProcessBuilder` seems like a confusing "red herring".

Comment: I ended up doing this:
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", "MyCurrentJarFile.jar", "path.to.my.class");

Comment: I only needed this so that i could set an environment variable, and then hop the the real main class.

Comment: @thefiscster510 Do you mind posting your code somewhere? I'm trying to do what you're doing and I'm having real trouble.